# How to visualize Atomicity in Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra, nosql, cassandra-3.0, atomic

As per [this datastax doc](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/dml/dml_atomicity_c.html) Atomicity in Cassandra is:

> In Cassandra, a write is atomic at the partition-level, meaning inserting or updating columns **in a row** is treated as one write operation.

Whereas according to [this datastax doc](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/dml/dmlTransactionsDiffer.html#Atomicity) Atomicity in Cassandra is:

> In Cassandra, a write operation is atomic at the partition level, meaning the insertions or updates of **two or more rows** in the same partition are treated as one write operation.

**My confusion is that whether atomicity is seen at a single row basis or it can have multiple rows included of a table at partition level?**

I assume it is a combination of both depending on the type of query we are executing in Cassandra.

**For Example :**

If I have an insert query, it will always be inserting one row in a partition. So Cassandra ensures that this row is inserted successfully at partition level.

But if I have update query whose where clause has a condition which is qualifying multiple rows then the update operation is atomic at partition level means either all qualified rows as per the condition will be updated or none will be.

**Is my understanding correct?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"row" and "partition" get conflated since previously row meant partition and now row means a part of a partition.

They are atomic to the partition. Keep in mind thats in reference to a single replica, so a or multiple rows in a batch containing 5 columns are all updated in a single operation on the one replica (no cross node isolation). If your setting `(key, value) VALUES ('abc', 'def')` you will never see just the `key` and not the `value` set. However you might make a read and only 1 replica has it set while other does not. Meaning depending on your replication factor and consistency level requested you will either see the whole thing or nothing. This can apply to multiple rows within a partition as well but you cannot update 2 rows with a single update statement without a batch (logged or unlogged).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But i am confused with the last statement. Isn't batch used when you want to execute queries on multiple table within a partition. Also, consider a query `update table_name set designation='SSE' where YOE>5; ` If this query selects multiple rows doesn't this query need to update all those rows to be considered atomic? For ex. if 3 rows have YOE>5 and if only one row is updated and then some failure occurs and write can't be performed on rem. two rows then how can this operation be atomic in a partition?

Comment: "If this query selects multiple rows" it will return an error. an update statement effects a single row. Deletes can create range tombstones but you cannot create range values

Comment: I tried a query `update table_name set column_name='c1' where primary_key='p1' and cluster_key in ('c1','c2')`. This query updated multiple rows. But it contradicts the statement `but you cannot update 2 rows with a single update statement without a batch (logged or unlogged)`. Could you please explain this? Does using `IN` with `Where` clause has something to do with `batch`?

Comment: yes thats true with equality and in clause you can do rows within a partition. And the way that it builds the partition builder that would still be a single applied mutation. You will not be able to do a YOE>5 though (slice in UpdateStatement throws UnsupportedOperationException). You can even do multiple partitions with an in clause. but they will be different mutations and not applied atomically unless in batch. Keep in mind that other then some semantics an UPDATE and INSERT are basically the same.